# Disable past dates from current date aspect

Tags: java, android, date, calendar

I have some piece of code here :

```
Calendar nowCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar minCalendar = new GregorianCalendar(nowCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), nowCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), nowCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH - 1));      
orderCalendarView.setMinDate(minCalendar.getTimeInMillis());
```

But this dont work... my year is = 1.

Does anyone know here how to disable past dates in android calendar control?

Thanks

Comment: your question is not clear, do you want to calculate current date and time?

Comment: No i just want to disable past dates so user cant tap on it. but with this vode my calendar starts from 1.1.1969